# How to incorporate moveable sensor (Lidar) into navigation stack

Tags: navigation, lidar, urdf, costmap, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a robot which will move using ros navigation stack with move_base. I am using Lidar Lite 2 Laser Rangefinder to detect obstacles and for mapping as well. I have two questions regarding the use of this lidar.

1. Shall I use LaserScan (in obstacle_layer) or Range message data (in RangeSensorLayer) to put obstacles into the costmap. I am confused because generally Lidar is considered as a Laser sensor so it should be providing data in LaserScan format. But this specific lidar is providing range data.
2. I am using a motor to rotate this lidar to cover 180 degrees of scan area. How can I let my obstacle layer know the current position of lidar so that the obstacle point is inserted at the correct place in the costmap. In my robot's urdf, I can add this sensor at one frame and it will be fixed to that place according to the urdf. Is there any method to resolve this issue ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229865/how-to-incorporate-moveable-sensor-(lidar)-into-navigation-stack/) by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use `LaserScan` messages, imo, and take care of the spinning logic in your laser scan publisher. Each `LaserScan` messsage's `ranges` field will be populated with, e.g., 180 degrees worth of LiDAR-Lite measurements.

Here are some guidelines and examples:

- http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Sensors
- [laser_scan_publisher_tutorial](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_tutorials/tree/indigo-devel/laser_scan_publisher_tutorial)
- https://github.com/rohbotics/xv_11_laser_driver
- https://github.com/ros-drivers/hokuyo_node

Keep in mind that you'll need some way of keeping track of your motor's / LiDAR's orientation. Some sort of encoder. (Unless you're using a stepper motor.)

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-03-24**:
I'm using a stepper motor to rotate my lidar lite, for design reasons. The stepper motor has been fixed at a rotation rate of 2Hz. The method you've described would therefore mean that there would be a lag of 0.5 seconds due to the refresh-rate. This isn't much lag, but can it be reduced further?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-24**:
That's what the `LaserScan` message's `time_increment` field is for :-) Check out this detailed explanation: http://answers.ros.org/question/198843/need-explanation-on-sensor_msgslaserscanmsg/?answer=198848#post-id-198848

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-03-28**:
alright. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Related to the part of the rotating lidar, I created an example that shows how to detect the closest obstacle to the whole system at any position of the rotation. The trick is to reference the obstacle to the `base_link` and use the `tf` to transform from the laser reference frame to the `base_link`reference frame.

I have done this in Python, using `tf2_ros` and `tf2_geometry_msgs`.

1st. Initialize the tf buffer and listener somewhere in your init function

```
buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer(rospy.Duration(1200.0)) 
tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(self.tf_buffer)
```

2nd. Do the actual transformation

```
transform = buffer.lookup_transform(target_frame, #destination frame
                                   pose_stamped_to_transform.header.frame_id, #source frame
                                   rospy.Time(0), #get the tf at first available time
                                   rospy.Duration(1.0)) #wait for 1 second

pose_transformed = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_pose(pose_stamped, transform)
```

You can [watch the video here](https://youtu.be/VfugbH16d1o) that shows a full example and how it looks in Rviz.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2017-12-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-12-09**:
This example is nice, but it doesn't really seem to be related to the question. The OP has a single-beam (point) lidar, but this example shows a line scanner.